# my toast not working, strange

Tags: android, toast

my code:

```
int LastSet = 2;

        if(LastSet == '2'){
            Toast.makeText(PrintName.this, "Jack Johnson", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

I think I used the right syntax and logic? nothing appear..

Comment: Please post language and platform

Comment: try to use getBaseContext();

instead of PrintName.this;

Comment: 2 and '2' are not same in terms of data type because you're comparing an int ( which is LastSet variable ) to '2' (char type)


change that '2' to 2

Answer (score 6):

You didn't specify which platform and programming language in the question (multiple platforms support toast notifications), so I'll assume Java on Android.  Look at the first two lines of your posted code:

```
int LastSet = 2;

if (LastSet == '2') {
    // Do something
}
```

You're setting `LastSet` to 2, which is an int, and then you're comparing it to the character '2', which is a completely different beast.  In Java, you can treat characters like ints for many purposes (including comparison with ints), but don't expect Java to treat 2 and '2' as the same thing *because they aren't*.  The number 2 is not the same as the character used to represent the digit 2.

Comment: just compare it to 2 not '2'... and please try to be more respectful

Comment: LastSet = "2" like this?

Comment: @Adam91 No, the solution is not to check against the string "2", because that's *a third thing*, different from either the number 2 or the character '2'.  Instead, check that `LastSet` is actually equal to the number 2.  There is rarely a good reason to compare an int to a char (and this is not such a situation).  Also, you can't write `LastSet = "2"` because the resulting program won't typecheck.  Or even better, just take out the if altogether - in the code you meant to write, the condition will always be true.

Comment: Just for the sake of being extremely explicit `LastSet == '2'` is wrong, `LastSet == "2"` is also wrong. `LastSet == 2` will work. However you don't need it, see above

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int LastSet = 2;

if(LastSet == 2){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Jack Johnson", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```